# AD / SYSVOL Version Mismatch on Default Domain Policy

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller, sysvol

I've created two test VMs in VMWare, both Server 2012 R2 Standard. One was promoted to a DC, with the domain name being test2.local. I modified the DNS record on the other server, and joined it to the test domain. Then I did (from an administrative command prompt) `gpupdate /force` and the `gpresult /H gpresult.html`. I looked in the gpresult.html file and saw a warning on the Default Domain Policy. It says: A fast link was detected (not worrying about now) and "AD / SYSVOL Version Mismatch" on Default Domain Policy. Opening up the Default Domain Policy under Applied GPOs shows that the SYSVOL number is 65535.

From what I have been able to gather, this mismatch occurs when there is security filtering and/or WMI filtering in place. I don't think I'm using either one of those, unless they are applied by default.

At this point, I just want a clean base that applies the unchanged Default Domain Policy to a machine without any errors. Then I can keep testing the GPO I'm building without wondering where the errors/warnings are coming from.

Comment: What does GPMC show for the user and computer versions (n/n)?

Comment: 65535 is always a sign that there was a failure to read the GPO. This could be caused by security filtering or WMI filtering, or read gpLink/gpOptions permissions missing, or replication delays, etc.

Comment: @GregAskew User version: 0/0 Computer version: 1/1

Comment: @RyanRies That's what I was reading, but I can't seem to find a way to fix it. I didn't do anything other than join the computer to the domain. Is there something special I need to do in order to allow the machine to read the GPO?

Comment: Does gpresult /h report the expected information when run on the domain controller?

Comment: @GregAskew No, it has the same problem. It shows both the Default Domain Policy AND the Default Domain Controller Policy as having an AD/SYSVOL Version Mismatch. And they're both 65535.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with reverting to the default, you can try running the following on the domain controller:

```
dcgpofix /ignoreschema /target:Domain
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875588.aspx

Comment: Still nothing... I'm seeing the version numbers increment in GPMC, but when I run gpresult on the domain controller, it still shows the SYSVOL version as 65535.

Comment: Try enabling group policy environment debug logging to see if that reveals anything:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4506.group-policy-debug-log-settings.aspx